# json parsing in windows phone 7 by given url

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, parsing

Please Help me, How to do json Parsing in windows phone 7 using Given URL Pexplain clearly from sample example URL  http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/546430/Parse-JSON-to-Csharp-in-WinRT-Silverlight-WPF-Wind
Not for your URL, but it's a general explanation.

Comment: Thank You for your response, can you explain how to do json parsing in windows phone from basic steps? because i don't know about that, i am learning this concept right now

Comment: personally, I think that article above already shows basic steps. If you don't understand something, you should ask more specific questions